# database schema for frequent relations of relations queries

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, database-schema, jsonschema, nosql

My app is in a way a social sharing platform which **heavily relies on searching through friend's friend / 2nd degree connections / relations-of-relations**.

Thus I am seeking help on the best schema for this app.

**App Setup** Each user has a share-able possession called a "Thing" and is living at one "Location". Each user has his/her friends & these friends have their own friends (with some overlap between friends).

**Use case** 
When a user needs a "Thing" (either because he runs out of it or is at different location), he simply performs a location based search in the app. The search returns list of friends in that location who have the "Thing" and also returns list of friend's friends who also have that "Thing". The user then messages his direct friends through the app's Chat functionality. But more importantly, user asks his friends to forward his "message-request" to their friends who match the criteria (location & Thing).

**Search Query for Database - expected results** This relations-of-relations search should return a two dimensional array: [a friend] [list of this friend's friends who match the search criteria]

**Data Model** User is modeled in as Person class. It is pretty simple and bare bone.

Additional expectations from Database schema:
Store chats and store profile photos

Note: Im developing in Angular4.

Your help is greatly appreciated!

```
// List of things of type string (in total 12)
import { Thing } from './thing.enum';

// Gender enum = MALE, FEMALE, UNKNOWN
import { Gender } from './gender.enum';

export class Person {
     public firstName: string;    
     public lastName: string;     
     public age: number;          
     public gender: Gender;       
     public phone: number;        

     // Users share Things
     public thing: Thing;        // User can only have 1 of 12 possible "Things"

     public city: string;              
     public country: string;           
     public countryISO: string; 
     public postalCode: string;        
     public placeID: string;           // Google Places API identifier
}
```

Comment: This is a very challenging question. The really difficult part is the security aspect as doing this task would mean that a user would not only have access to their friends data but would also be able to access *any* users data. i.e. every user will need to be able to query for a 'Thing" on all uses nodes - which seems pretty insecure. The question is also a bit ambiguous as to know who has a 'Thing' you will need to query the entire database, and therefore would know everyone that has a 'Thing'. If you know that, then you could send them a message directly.

Comment: In terms of security, I have two things in mind. When showing search results of 2nd degree connections. I will only show number & not real names. For example say User-A makes the search and User-B has 30 friends who have the _Thing, then User-A will only see know that much & not the names of User-B's friends. Now it is up to User-B to forward the request to his/her friends. Plus Im thinking of creating on-the-fly Chat-rooms for each of these searches. People who are willing to share can join the chat-room without having to _friend User-A just to be able to chat.